# Descobrir turno se baseando por um horario de uma determinada data em ORACLE/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqldeveloper, oracle12c

Em uma tabela X tenho uma coluna date que também retorna o horário, gostaria de saber se, me baseando nesse horário, tenho como criar uma coluna com o nome do turno. ex( se tem um dado 20-02-2002  06:00:00  quero que apareça na coluna o char 'Manhã').
alguma ideia ?

Answer (score 1):

Em Oracle isto pode ser feito através da criação de uma coluna virtual. Quando a tabela é acedida as colunas virtuais aparentam ser iguais às colunas ditas normais, no entanto o seu valor é derivado/calculado ao invés de ser guardado em memória.

A sintaxe para definir uma coluna virtual é a seguinte:

> NOME_DA_COLUNA [TIPO_DE_DADOS] [GENERATED ALWAYS] AS (EXPRESSÃO)
>   [VIRTUAL]

Fica aqui um exmplo de como alterar uma tabela existente para adicionar uma coluna virtual:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela_X
  ADD TURNO GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(COLUNA_DATE, 'hh24:mi:ss') < '12:00:00' THEN 'Manhã' WHEN TO_CHAR(COLUNA_DATE, 'hh24:mi:ss') < '18:00:00' THEN 'Tarde' ELSE 'Noite' END));
```

Neste exemplo, as horas no intervalo 00:00 até às 12:00 correspondem ao turno da manhã, entre as 12h00 e as 18h00 correspondem à tarde e as restantes correspondem ao turno da noite.

Será pois necessário alterar a condição na instrução CASE de acordo com a sua necessidade.

Comment: Faltou um "then 'tarde' ...

Comment: Obrigado @Motta